# how to send request parmater to .net webservice from android?

Tags: android, soap

Sending request parameter to the given structure in image returns null response.So How to send request parameter and receive response parameters according to the structure given in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCUmv.png). Please can anyone help me out of this?

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("extTransactionId", "-99999");
request.addProperty("password", "Apiuser@123");
AttributeInfo ai = new AttributeInfo();
ai.name = "UserName";
ai.type = AttributeInfo.STRING_CLASS;
ai.setValue("sarvoday507");
request.addAttribute(ai);
request.addProperty("requestDate", "2015-02-24T06:38:00");
request.addProperty("systemId", "Apiuser");
request.addProperty("UAN", "");
```

Comment: `> 1k` such a questions already in SO

Comment: But that does not work for me.just check the structure of my image and can you help me out?

Comment: SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
             request.addProperty("extTransactionId", "-99999");
             request.addProperty("password", "Apiuser@123");
AttributeInfo ai = new AttributeInfo();
             ai.name = "UserName";
             ai.type = AttributeInfo.STRING_CLASS;
             ai.setValue("sarvoday507");
             
             request.addAttribute(ai);
             request.addProperty("requestDate", "2015-02-24T06:38:00");
             request.addProperty("systemId", "Apiuser");
             request.addProperty("UAN", "");

Answer (score 0):

Create a main request `SoapObject` and add "UserName" property to this. Create "Request" `SoapObject`, add the rest of the properties to this and add this "Request" `SoapObject` to main request `SoapObject`.

It will be something like this,

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "GetCustomerDetail");
    request.addProperty("UserName", username);

    SoapObject requestInner = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Request");
    requestInner.addProperty("requestDate", "2015-02-24T06:38:00");
    requestInner.addProperty("extTransactionId", "-99999");
    requestInner.addProperty("systemId", "Apiuser");
    requestInner.addProperty("password", "Apiuser@123");
    requestInner.addProperty("UAN", "");

    request.addSoapObject(requestInner);
```

Comment: its not working..it gives me below error
Error: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500

Comment: @HarshShah HTTP status 500 means internal server error! Check at the server logs to see what caused it.