# Add attribute soapserializationenvelope?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, attributes

I send request to web service: 
how to add one attribute to envelope object
some method to add, probe of methods, but none work, I thought prefixes were added by the Envelope, add the tag

Add envelope object and Add header with Elements

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
request.addProperty("sID", user);

Element[] header = new Element[1];
header[0] = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "credendtials" );
Element tagUser = new Element().createElement(null, "UserName");
tagUser.addChild(Node.TEXT, valUSER);
header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, tagUser);
Element tagPass = new Element().createElement(null, "UserPassword");
tagPass.addChild(Node.TEXT, valPASS);
header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, tagPass);
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.headerOut = header;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
transporte.debug = true;
```

This is request estructure, this send to web service

```
  <v:Envelope
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header>
       <n0:Credentials  xmlns:n0="http://254.254.254.254:9999">
          <UserName></UserName>
          <UserPassword></UserPassword>
       </n0:Credentials>
    </v:Header>
   <v:Body>
   <Emp xmlns="http://254.254.254.254:9999">
     <sID></sID>
   </Emp>
 </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I need add attribute to tag :

```
  <v:Envelope
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns="http://254.254.254.254:9999">
    <v:Header>
       <n0:Credentials xmlns:n0="http://254.254.254.254:9999">
          <UserName></UserName>
          <UserPassword></UserPassword>
       </n0:Credentials>
    </v:Header>
   <v:Body>
   <Emp xmlns="http://254.254.254.254:9999">
     <sID></sID>
   </Emp>
 </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please refer this SO thread for adding header, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613675/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap2-android

Comment: Thanks.... It similar, header i create easy, but not attibutes of envelope object

Comment: Can you add all your code for making the SOAP request? Also show the structure of the current soap request object you are creating.

Comment: ok add the code which built the Envelope....

Comment: See this thread how to add request parameters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037725/how-to-send-request-parmater-to-net-webservice-from-android/35038390#35038390

Comment: i need add one attribute to tag <envelope>

Comment: You need to create Emp tag and sID tag inside it.